# PHP REGEX separate by different criteria

Tags: php

I'm trying to separate some strings by different criteria but I can't get the desired results.

Here are 3 examples:

```
$ppl[0] = "Balko, Vlado     \"Panelбk\" (2008) {Byt na tretom (#1.55)}";
$ppl[1] = "'Abd Al-Hamid, Ja'far    A Two Hour Delay (2001)";
$ppl[2] = "'t Hoen, Frans       De reьnie (1963) (TV)";
```

I'm currently using this for the last 2:

```
$pattern = '#,|\t|\(#'
```

But I will get and empty space. 
result:

```
Array ( [0] => 'Abd Al-Hamid [1] => Ja'far [2] => A Two Hour Delay [3] => 2001) )
Array ( [0] => 't Hoen [1] => Frans [2] => [3] => De reünie [4] => 1963) [5] => TV) )
```

As for the 1st expression I used another pattern but I still get empty spaces. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Thanks this helped indeed. I tried using a modified version on the first string:

```
$pattern4 = '#[",\t]+|[{}]+|[()]+#';
```

However I still get an empty space:

```
Array ( [0] => Balko [1] => Vlado [2] => Panelák [3] => [4] => 2008 [5] => [6] => Byt na tretom [7] => #1.55 [8] => [9] => )
```

What should I do? I think that the " and the brackets are causing the problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would surmise you have two tabs as separator in your second and third example string. (Can't see that here, the SO editor converts them into spaces).

But you could adapt your regex slightly in that case:

```
 $pattern = '#,|\t+|\(#'
```

Or simpler even:

```
 $pattern = '#[,\t(]+#'
```

And the alternatve, btw, would be just applying `array_filter()` on the result arrays to remove the empty entries.